# Nativescript resource images require iOS simulator reset

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript

I was following this guide: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/image-resources#loading-icons-in-the-tabview-from-the-resources

Used their service: http://nsimage.brosteins.com/ for iOS static images.

And placed them under:

- "app/App_Resources/iOS/map.png"
- "app/App_Resources/iOS/map@2x.png"
- "app/App_Resources/iOS/map@3x.png"

Then trying to use it on a TabViewItem:

```
<TabView>
  <TabViewItem title="Tab Item" iconSource="res://map"/>
</TabView>
```

But when app is relaunched in iOS simulator, this image doesn't appear, i have to "Erase all content and Settings", only then they show up. Is it by design or bug? Using Nativescript 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build - stop any tns command already running and delete platforms folder then run the commands again.

If still doesn't work, it may be the rendering mode so try setting `iosIconRenderingMode` to `alwaysOriginal`.

```
<TabView iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal">
```

Comment: I already tried to remove `tns platform remove ios` - didn't help. `iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal"` is set either. Only way is to reset the simulator.